# Как работают фабрики в тестах rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста понять логику работы тестов моделей с помощью фабрик.

Вот сам тест:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe News do
  news1 = FactoryGirl.create(:news)
  news2 = FactoryGirl.create(:news)
  news1.title.should == "1 test news title"
  news2.title.should == "2 test news title"
end
```

Вот фабрика

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :news do
    sequence(:title) { |i| "#{i} test news title"}
    sequence(:description) { |i| "#{i} test news description, must have minimum 40 letters"}
    user_id 1
    news_poster { fixture_file_upload "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/images/calendar.png", 'image/png' }
  end
end
```

И модель News

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :news_poster, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :news_poster, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 40 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 40, maximum: 250 }
  validates :news_poster, presence: true
end
```

По моей логике, каждый раз при запуске теста в тестовой БД должны создаваться новые записи с измененной цифрой "i"

```
sequence(:title) { |i| "#{i} test news title"}
```

И при первом запуске теста все работает, создаются записи с title - "1 test news title" и "2 test news title" - тест проходит успешно, но при повторном - цифра 1 и 2 не меняется на 3 и 4 как я думал, и уже выскакивает ошибка. Возможно я не правильно строю логику тестов?

Comment: Используете ли в работе DatabaseCleaner? Какая СУБД используется для в качестве базы данных? Такое ощущение, что у вас старые данные не удаляются перед тестами.

Comment: @cheops только узнал про этот гем, но пока не понимаю как его использовать. (Да, данные не удалялись из БД). 
Записал в Gemfile; Создал папку spec/support и добавил туда файл  database_cleaner.rb; в rails_helper.rb вызвал так - require 'database_cleaner'; Сделал все по этой ссылке в общем (https://github.com/eliotsykes/rspec-rails-examples/blob/master/spec/support/database_cleaner.rb) кроме 0 пункта, что там должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sequence` предназначен для генрации **гарантированно разных** значений, основываясь на последовательности натуральных чисел.

Пользовались `Faker`? Он выдаёт красивые, правдоподобные и **случайные** идентификаторы. И из-за этого есть ненулевая вероятность, что тесты упадут **"просто так"** (рандом выдаст пару одинаковых значений и уникальность грохнется) и при повторном запуске **пройдут**. Частота? В моём случае примерно 4 раза за полгода, в условиях CI. Всегда неожиданно, пугающе и загадочно.

И да, при каждом тестовом прогоне `sequence` будет генерировать последовательность сначала, поскольку в лучших традициях тестирования начинать тесты *с базы **без** данных* и не строить предположений о том, что в базе было ранее и на каких местах остановились последовательности первичных ключей.

Это я всё к чему.
**Скорее всего, вы тестируете то, на что вашему приложению должно быть наплевать,** в частности, то, каким способом БД раздаёт первичные ключи. Потому что [ситуация может измениться](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/announcing-snowflake) и было бы странно переписывать тесты, которые требований к этому не имеют.

Answer (score 1):

С высокой долей вероятности у вас где-то используется первичный ключ, которому назначаются уникальные значения. Сами же записи в таблицах тестовой базы данных либо не удаляются, либо удаляются по delete-стратегии, когда новые записи не могут принимать значения уже удаленных записей.

Для предотвращения описанной вами ситуации, стараются для каждого теста предоставлять базу данных в одном и том же состоянии - очищая ее от старых значений перед каждым тестом. Для этого удобно воспользоваться гемом [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner). После его установки, добавьте в spec/rails_helper.rb в блок `RSpec.configure do |config|` следующие строки

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

В результате база данных будет очищаться перед каждым новым тестом. Стратегия truncation будет гарантировать, что первичные ключи будут отсчитываться каждый раз от 1, а не от последнего вставленного значения (как происходит в вашем случае).

Comment: Все сделал точно так, но пока БД не очищается и вылазит ошибка валидации - Title has already been taken

Comment: Записи в тестовой базе данных остаются даже после прогона всех тестов?

Comment: Да, насколько я понимаю гем  Database Cleaner не срабатывает, возможно не так подключил, хотя все должно работать.